# Techniques for disproving group isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose I wanted to find out if $f:\mathbb{Z}_6\rightarrow S_3$ is an isomorphism. Clearly, $f$ is bijective. It remains to show that $f(a+b)=f(a)\circ f(b)\;\forall a,b\in \mathbb{Z}_6$. For this step, I made up the following technique to try to *disprove* isomorphism:

Make a list of all $a*a$ for each element $a$. We immediately see that $S_3$ contains four elements equal to their own inverses (satisfying $a=a^{-1}$), but $\mathbb{Z}_6$ only contains two elements equal to their own inverses. Therefore, $f$ not an isomorphism.

I also look for other patterns by analyzing this list. Consider the values of $a*a$ for each $a\in \mathbb{Z}_6$, listed here: $ \{0, 2, 4, 0, 2, 4\}$. We can see there are three "pairs": one for 0, one for 2, one for 4. If the list of $a*a$ for a different group, say $G$, has the following: $\{a,a,a,b,b,c\}$ then we know that $G\not\cong\mathbb{Z}_6$ simply because $G$'s list does not contain three "pairs" of elements that $\mathbb{Z}_6$'s list did.

Do you think this is a good way to go about disproving isomorphism? What other techniques do you recommend (e.g. if $G$ is abelian but $H$ is not, $G\not\cong H$)? I am doing self-study, and textbook failed to teach me any actual methods for showing isomorphism.

I have posted this question simply to learn techniques and new perspectives for approaching these types of problems. I want to have a general understanding of the different ways we might prove/disprove group isomorphism for different types of problems. Thank you.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_6$ is Abelian and $S_3$ isn't. That's a proof. If more detail is required, you can show that $\mathbb{Z}_6$ is Abelian and find a pair of permutations in $S_3$ that don't commute. And you can show that isomorphism preserves Abelian-ness.

Comment: I think it is worth noting that until you tell us what $f$ is, you don't know whether it is a bijection. For instance $f(x) = e$ is a group homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}_6 \rightarrow S_3$, but it is not a bijection.

Comment: How can you say "clearly $f$ is bijective" when you haven't defined what $f$ is?

Comment: @anon, I see what you are saying. Constructing $f$ should be the last step of my proof, after I have proven $f(ab)=f(a)f(b)$ and can then show the one-to-one correspondence between elements.

Answer (score 2):

You could also prove this by saying that $\mathbb{Z}_6$ is abelian while $S_3$ is not (hence they are not isomorphic).

Comment: That seems to be a much quicker solution for this specific problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As user4894 and Thomas have pointed out, in this case, one group is abelian while the other is not, so they cannot be isomorphic. As you are looking for techniques to disprove two groups are isomorphic, here is a different proof.

First note that if $f : G \to H$ is an isomorphism and $g \in G$ has order $n$, then $f(g) \in H$ has order $n$. As $f$ is a bijection, we see that the number of elements of $G$ of order $n$ is equal to the number of elements of $H$ of order $n$. Therefore, one way to disprove that two groups are isomorphic is to show that they have a different number of elements of a given order.

In this example, $\mathbb{Z}_6$ has an element of order $6$, namely $1 \in \mathbb{Z}_6$, but every element of $S_3$ has order $1$, $2$, or $3$. As $\mathbb{Z}_6$ and $S_3$ have a different number of elements of order $6$, they are not isomorphic.